# How do you print out the output in Java Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to physically print out my output box (using a printer) for a class.

Can someone please explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing the console from eclipse, you can output all your `System.out.println()` directly to a file.  Basically, you are using the file as a debugger instead of the console window. To do this, you can use the code below.

```
import java.io.*;
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("debuggerOutput.txt", "UTF-8");
//in your class constructor, you will need to add some exception throws
write.println("I used to be in the debugger, but now I go in the file!!")
```

For each `System.out.println()`, add an extra `write.println()` with the same thing in the parenthesis so it outputs to the file what goes in the console.
Then, you will see all your output in a file that you can easily print.
At the end, make sure to `write.close()`

Full code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("The line");

    writer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I keep getting these error messages when I use the initialization code: unhandled exception type FileNotFound and unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncoding

Comment: did you add all the throws in the class constructor?

Comment: What throws are you talking about? I am relatively new to Java, so I apologize for my ineptitude.

Comment: What error? After your `(String[] args)`, you must have `throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException`

Comment: Does that work? I added the full code into the answer.  You will have to change the class name if you copy it.

Comment: Ignore my previous post. I got it down now. Thanks!